# Remove "No main class detected" warning in SBT

Tags: sbt

I have a multi-module SBT project. Some of the modules produce JARs with main classes and can be started with `java -jar` but most don't.

However when I run (or compile, or anything else) one of the modules (`sbt foo/run`) I get a warning per library module.

```
[warn] No main class detected
```

How can I remove those warnings?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This warning is [considered a bug](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/pull/1766) in sbt 0.13.7 and it will be removed in sbt 0.13.8.